# Keepalived vrrp_script does not failover

Tags: centos, haproxy, failover

I have 2 nodes with keepalived and haproxy services (CentOS7).
If I'm shutdown one node all working fine. But I want to failover the VIPS if haproxy  is down.

This is 1st node config:

```
  vrrp_script ha_check {
script "/etc/keepalived/haproxy_check"
interval 2
weight 21
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state MASTER
        interface eno16777984
        virtual_router_id 151
        priority 101
        advert_int 1
        authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 11111
                        }
        virtual_ipaddress {
                10.0.100.233
                            }
        smtp_alert
track_script {
ha_check
}
}
```

2nd node:

```
vrrp_script ha_check {
script "/etc/keepalived/haproxy_check"
interval 2
fall 2
rise 2
timeout 1
weight 2
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state BACKUP
        interface eno16777984
        virtual_router_id 151
        priority 100
        advert_int 1
        authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 11111
                        }
        virtual_ipaddress {
                10.0.100.233
                            }
        smtp_alert
track_script {
ha_check
}
}
```

cat /etc/keepalived/haproxy_check

```
systemctl status haproxy | grep "inactive"
```

When I stop haproxy it still does not failover the VIPs to the next
host.

```
[root@cks-hatest1 keepalived]# tail /var/log/messages
Nov 30 10:35:24 cks-hatest1 Keepalived_vrrp[5891]: VRRP_Script(ha_check) failed
Nov 30 10:35:33 cks-hatest1 systemd: Started HAProxy Load Balancer.
Nov 30 10:35:45 cks-hatest1 systemd: Stopping HAProxy Load Balancer...
Nov 30 10:35:45 cks-hatest1 systemd: Stopped HAProxy Load Balancer.
Nov 30 10:35:46 cks-hatest1 Keepalived_vrrp[5891]: VRRP_Script(ha_check) succeeded
```

What I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your script you are checking if

```
systemctl status haproxy
```

contains keyword "inactive". Is that the value you get when you stop haproxy service manually?

As soon as haproxy service is stopped your logs contains it is started again. Can you verify that?

Also, try with replacing the script as

```
script "killall -0 haproxy"
```

Comment: `[root@cks-hatest1 ~]# systemctl start haproxy  [root@cks-hatest1 ~]# /etc/keepalived/haproxy_check  [root@cks-hatest1 ~]# systemctl stop haproxy  [root@cks-hatest1 ~]# /etc/keepalived/haproxy_check Active: inactive (dead)` 

killall -0 haproxy not working too


`cks-hatest1 Keepalived_vrrp[5891]: VRRP_Script(ha_check) succeeded`
but nothing going on

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. Try this for example:

```
vrrp_script check_haproxy {
    script "pidof haproxy"
    interval 2
    weight 2
}
```

In the end of config you should add following part too:

```
track_script {
    check_haproxy
}
```